# HTTP, PHP: Return base64 image png as download

Tags: php, symfony, http, download

I have a base64 representation of an png image and want to return a download stream of that image.

So when the user opens the url, a download of that image is returned. How can I achieve this in PHP? I'm using Symfony 2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are in a Controller class of the Symfony framework, so is better you deal with the corrispondent framework object as follow:

```
public function imageDownloadAction()
{
  .....
    // Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response 
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($image);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename);

    return $response;

}
```